# Access Denied attaching a database through network

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2012, file-permissions

SQL Server 2012 instance is running on `MyDatabaseServer`. I failed to attach database when I attach database on another machine on the network.

- If I login to `MyMachine`, open SSMS, connect to `MyDatabaseServer\MyDB` and run the following code, it ***FAILS***.
- If I login to `MyDatabaseServer`, open SSMS, connect to `MyDatabaseServer\MyDB` and run the following code, it ***WORKS***.

I need it to run on another machine other than the DB server itself. What should I do???

Note 1: The code I ran:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON 
    ( FILENAME = N'\\MyFileserver\MyFolder\MyDatabase.MDF'),
    ( FILENAME = N'\\MyFileserver\MyFolder\MyDatabase_Log.LDF')
     FOR ATTACH
```

It returns:

> Unable to open the physical file "\MyFileserver\MyFolder\MyDatabase.MDF". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

Note 2: The account to run SSMS and the service account to run SQL Server both have full control permission to `\\\\MyFileserver\\MyFolder\\` as well as `MyDatabase.MDF`

Note 3: I am able to connect to the DB `MyDatabaseServer\MyDB` on both machines SSMS.

Note 4: It is SQL Server 2012. `MyDatabaseServer` is a Windows Server 2012. `MyMachine` is Windows 7.

Comment: you can't attached the same set of files to 2 diff database server

Comment: There is only one sql server here. The difference is the machine I use to connect to the DB using ssms. May be I edit the question a bit.

Comment: it doesn't matter what machine you are running SSMS. Are you login to MyDatabaseServer\MyDB using the same login credential on both machine ?

Comment: It feels weird to me as well. I have logged in with the same credential. But it only works when runs on the DB server itself, failed when runs on any other machines.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the trace flag?

Comment: Do you mean -T1807? Yes, it is set. And some say it is not needed on sql server since 2008.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server database must be on the same machine as the server is installed

Comment: It does not. It can be attached and function well on a network location.
Please check: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/01/sql-server-databases-on-network-shares-nas/